# (failed to post notification on channel) error in android 8 or later

Tags: android, notifications, android-service, android-8.0-oreo, background-service

i try to startForegroundService in android studio with java 
i use a service with notification .
it's work very good in android lower 8 . but i get (failed to post notification on channel) error in android 8 or later .

i write some code from this site :
https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/foreground-service

```
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
  0, notificationIntent, 0);

Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
  .setContentTitle("Example Service")
  .setContentText(input)
  .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
  .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
  .build();

startForeground(1, notification);
```

my code is that site codes.

please see it.

Comment: Did you create the `NotificationChannel` somewhere?

Comment: hi Mike , Yes i Full Copy That Site Codes And He Create It On App.class

Comment: Are you sure you specified `App` as the `android:name` on the `<application>` element in your manifest?

Comment: I'm not sure . i had to go check it

Comment: Thank You Mike. My Problem Solved with Your Help